# Writing image value to field_collection object

Tags: 7, nodes, entities

I'm creating a field collection item  and saving it via entity_create, and it all works great as long as I don't have an image tied to it. As soon as I do, I get an error, and it looks like this in the watchdog table:

```
    a:6:{s:5:"%type";s:12:"PDOException";s:8:"!message";s:516:"SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column &#039;fid&#039; cannot be null: INSERT INTO {file_usage} (fid, module, type, id, count) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4); Array
(
    [:db_insert_placeholder_0] =&gt; 
    [:db_insert_placeholder_1] =&gt; file
    [:db_insert_placeholder_2] =&gt; field_collection_item
    [:db_insert_placeholder_3] =&gt; 50
    [:db_insert_placeholder_4] =&gt; 1
)
";s:9:"%function";s:16:"file_usage_add()";s:5:"%file";s:43:"C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\includes\file.inc";s:5:"%line";i:663;s:14:"severity_level";i:3;}
```

My code looks like this:

```
$values = array(
    'field_name' => 'field_bp_images',
    'field_bp_image_title' => array( LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $title)), ),
    'field_bp_image_file' => array( LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $fid)), ), 
    'field_bp_image_photographer_name' => array( LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $photographer)), ),
    'field_bp_image_photo_flag' => array( LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('value' => $is_photo)), ), 
  );
}

$field_collection_item  = entity_create('field_collection_item', $values);
#Attach to the node
$field_collection_item->setHostEntity('node', $node); 

// # Save field-collection item.
$field_collection_item->save();
```

My $fid is definitely populated, but I am still getting that error telling me my fid cannot be null. I'm guessing I need to provide more elements to the array, but not sure what keys to give, or how many. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column name for an image field is `fid` (not `value`), so you just need to change this bit of your `$values` array:

```
'field_bp_image_file' => array( LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('fid' => $fid)), ),
```

Comment: Clive, Thanks once again, that seems to have helped, once. I was updating only one record. Subsequent tries with several records produced errors such as these:
  "Warning: Illegal string offset 'field' in DatabaseCondition->__clone() (line 1895 of C:\xampp\htdocs\LLIS-NPAD\includes\database\query.inc)."
  and
"Recoverable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string". I'm unsure how to troubleshoot this, so I appreciate additional thoughts.

Comment: Clive, I'm still struggling with this. Any chance you can advice on how to find out what an image field expects? Just passing it the fid doesn't seem to be enough

Comment: Looks like I just needed to set the image up like this:      'field_bp_image_file' => array( LANGUAGE_NONE => array(array('fid' => $fid,'display'=>1,'description'=>'' )), ). Now to figure out which properties are required by word and other files, I can get this thing dones!